# How to update Docker interpreter when requirements.txt is updated

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I added some libraries to requirement.txt but Docker interpreter in Pycharm does not update and when I installed some library in Docker container I get this error some error and warning.
this is warning = WARNING: The directory '/home/shop/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.

and this is error = ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3'
Check the permissions.

you can see my Dockerfile.

```
FROM hemanhp/djbase:4.2.4


COPY ./requirements /requirements
COPY ./scripts /scripts
COPY ./src /src

WORKDIR src

EXPOSE 8000

RUN /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements/development.txt


RUN chmod -R +x /scripts && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home shop && \
    chown -R shop:shop /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol


ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:$PATH"

USER shop

CMD ["run.sh"]
```

Comment: What commands exactly are you running?  I'd expect a typical workflow to be to install and validate the updated library in a non-Docker virtual environment, run `pip freeze` to regenerate the `requirements.txt` file, and then run `docker build` again to recreate the image.

Comment: The problem is that you run `pip install ...` and after it change the user. The environment and the cache are created and installed by root not shop user.